# Custom text expansion or hotkeys in MS SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms, hotkeys

I have to write a number of queries in SQL Server Management Studio, most of which, however, are not in my current database, but to a remote one. So, any simple select query looks like:

select * from [top_database].subdatabase.subsubdatabase.actualtable

where all I want to do is write

select * from actualtable

Is there any way that I can customize SQL Server so that I hit some hotkey or expand a very minimal text which will then give me

[top_database].subdatabase.subsubdatabase.

right after my cursor?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [synonym](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544.aspx) to your remote tables and use that synonym when you write queries. You can have a db at your server with all the synonyms you are likely to use. More work the first time you query a table but less work the next time.

```
create synonym TableName for LinkedServerName.DataBaseName.SchemaName.TableName
```

Then you can do

```
select *
from TableName
```

Not really an answer to your question but it could be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, this is actually a good solution to my problem. However, since I don't have create synonym permission on my current database, I'm still looking for an editor-level solution. I will ask for permission asap.

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually mean...

[linker server].[data base].[schema].[object]?

If so, as far as I am aware, you have to specify all parts of this.  Intelli-sense exists in later versions of management studio, but I am not aware of it being able to expand names that exist on a linked server.

(I presume this is because the SQL Server, not the management studio client, would need to open a connection to the Linked Server to ascertain that information.)

Comment: +1 - Your best option is to put them in a notepad on another monitor and `CTRL+C` `CTRL+V`

Comment: Yes, you are right in your first remark. Also, I'm not debating whether this syntax is explicitly required; I know it is, otherwise there could be name collision between various servers. However, all I'm looking for is a simple way, from an editing standpoint, to merely add a hotkey when SQL Server has focus, so that I can insert 

linker server].[data base].[schema].

automatically, and not have to type it every time.

Comment: I've marked this as a favourite as I'm intrigued if there are any Useful answers.  But as far as I know, you're stuck with copy and paste.

Comment: Apologies if I sounded patronising!  Only questioned that as to establish if you meant a Linked Server, as that would be the point at which the management studio client would hit a different limitting factor.